# java synthesizer that can use dls or sf2 files

Tags: java, audio, midi, javasound, synthesizer

I am looking for a synthesizer that I can use with javax.sound.midi classes which allows me to use soundbank formats other than one by Beatnik. I could not find one and a [6 years old information](http://jsresources.org/faq_midi.html#soundfont) tells me that there are none available. However I wonder if new projects have come up since.

I have asked a [related question](https://superuser.com/questions/459594/midi-software-synthesizer-that-plays-wave-files) with a different approach to playing my own samples according to a midi sequence generated by a sequencer in java, but to no avail.

Comment: I just read more into the different java versions and it seems that Java 7 allows the use of dls and sf2 soundbank. I'll report back once I've figured it out.

Comment: Java 7 allows the use of those formats because it switched to a different sound api implementation called Gervill. I'm currently trying to figure out if I can use the Gervill jar directly so it doesn't matter which version of Java I use.

Comment: @gsingh3022, I am using Gervill directly now. It works quite well, I used their tests to understand the functionality of the library. I am happy to answer questions about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 7 sf2-soundbanks can be loaded via the class SF2Soundbank which worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the high quality one offered at [Java Sound API: Soundbanks](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/soundbanks.html).

Comment: I don't understand. I am looking to play my own samples (not musical instruments, but syllables that are sampled). Would the high quality soundbank be help in any way, e.g. would it be extendible?

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I though the question was just about the quality of the standard instrument set of the sound bank, and missed the subtlety of 'own sounds'.